# HTTP Request and JSON parsing in Swift

Tags: json, swift, http, dialogflow-es

So, I'm trying to make a very simple watchOS app in XCode. It consists of a button, two labels and a separator between the two labels. It is a digital assistant app, and needs to interface with Dialogflow (https://dialogflow.com).

The button calls the `presentTextInputController` function, and I want to use that result as a query to my Dialogflow agent.

I need to make an HTTP request, which in JS would look more like this:

```
{
url:"https://api.api.ai/v1/query",
method:"post",
body:JSON.stringify({query:"userInput",lang:"en-US",sessionID:"yaydevdiner"}),
headers:{
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
Authorization:"Bearer <auth_token>"
}
}
```

The response is a JSON object, and I need to access the `jsonObject["result"]["speech"]` value as a String to use `Label.setText()`

Everything I've tried has given errors about type Any and other such things. I also haven't been able to do much debugging since the `print` output isn't showing up in XCode.

I must mention that I'm an extreme beginner to Swift, and I am not good at handling their  types and casting and unpacking and things like that.

Could someone show me how I might handle this request and the subsequent processing of the JSON?

Here is my current code:

```
//HTTP Request

            let parameters = [

                "query":name![0] as? String,

                "lang":"en-US",

                "sessionID":"yaydevdiner"

            ];



            //create the url with URL

            let url = URL(string: "https://api.api.ai/v1/query")! //change the url



            //create the session object

            let session = URLSession.shared



            //now create the URLRequest object using the url object

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)

            request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST



            do {

                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

            } catch let error {

                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }



            request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            request.addValue("Bearer f786fef55008491fb8422cea2be85eb1", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")



            //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in



                guard error == nil else {

                    return

                }



                guard let data = data else {

                    return

                }



                do {

                    //create json object from data

                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject (with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] {

                        self.Response.setText(json["result"]["string"]);

                    }

                } catch let error {

                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                }

            })

            task.resume()

        }
```

`Response` is a text label.

This code gives me an error saying I should have a question mark between 
`json["result"]` and `["speech"]`. When I do this, it gives me another error saying "Type Any has no subscript members".

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+parse+json). Questions about JSON parsing are one of the most frequently asked questions here on SO. And without knowing the JSON the question cannot be answered anyway.

Comment: First, I did do a lot of searching on here, but nothing was working, and I couldn't figure out why because of my inability to use the `print` function.

Also, all you need to know about the JSON is right in the question; all I need from it looks like this:
{
"request":{
"speech":"Text"
}
}

Comment: Please add the code you have problems with. And there is no JSON at all in the question.

Comment: Ok, as soon as I can get it. It's on an iMac which is currently unavailable to me. Otherwise I would have had the code there from the start.

Comment: As to your comment about the JSON, it is implied here:
"The response is a JSON object, and I need to access the jsonObject["result"]["speech"] value as a String to use Label.setText()"

Comment: Please, the actual JSON **cannot** be inferred from `jsonObject["result"]["speech"]`. The **types** are very important.

Comment: Ok, I apologise for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have the code now, I'm updating the post.

Comment: `self.Response.setText(json["result"] as? [String:Any])` What's `Response` you look like you are trying to set its text with a dictionary?

Comment: Oh, yes. `Response` is a label, and I know I can't set it as a dictionary. I didn't finish writing that line last time. I'll explain more in the post

Comment: Once again, *... without knowing the JSON the question cannot be answered*. The exact JSON. Insert the following two lines right after `do {` and post the result : `let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` `print(jsonString)`

Comment: And again, I cannot use `print`

Comment: I don't know whether the HTTP request is even working at this point. I have no way of debugging at all.

Comment: The JSON reponse, as I said before, should be of this form: {"result":{"speech":"String"}}

Comment: You *said before* `{ "request":{ "speech":"Text" } }` which is confusing because it doesn't match the code. Coding is a very precise subject. 

Comment: Ah, I see. I keep getting mixed up between "request" and "result", because as common letters go they are very similar. It was a silly mistake. I know Coding is somewhat precise; I'm certainly not a newbie to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

Because XCode automatically makes an iOS app with the watchOS app, I decided to try debugging in the iOS app until I got the HTTP request and JSON parsing right.

Inside the JSONSerialization if statement, I had to add another if statement:

```
if let result = responseJSON["result"] as? [String:Any]{
self.Response.setText(result!["speech"] as? String ?? "Network error Occurred")
}
```

Thanks for the help from vadian!